# subprocess get stucks at poller.poll()

Tags: python, matlab, nipype

I'm trying to run a simple matlab interface on Nipype as below, but somehow it gets stuck in run() code. My command line does not proceed anymore . But it works perfectly if I copy mlab.cmdline (matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -singleCompThread -r "addpath('/somepath');pyscript;exit") and past it to the Command Line.

```
import nipype.interfaces.matlab as matlab

mlab = matlab.MatlabCommand()
mlab.inputs.script = """ 1+2 """

print mlab.cmdline
res = mlab.run()

print res.runtime
```

here is ipython keyboard interruption :

```
    ^C---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyboardInterrupt                         Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/py3compat.pyc in execfile(fname, *where)
    173             else:
    174                 filename = fname
--> 175             __builtin__.execfile(filename, *where)

/new_home/intern2012/yasin/example.py in <module>()
      6
      7 print mlab.cmdline
----> 8 res = mlab.run()
      9
     10 print res.runtime

/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/nipype/interfaces/base.pyc in run(self, **inputs)
    944                         version=self.version)
    945         try:
--> 946             runtime = self._run_interface(runtime)
    947             outputs = self.aggregate_outputs(runtime)
    948             runtime.endTime = dt.isoformat(dt.utcnow())

/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/nipype/interfaces/matlab.pyc in _run_interface(self, runtime)
    136     def _run_interface(self,runtime):
    137         self.inputs.terminal_output = 'allatonce'
--> 138         runtime = super(MatlabCommand, self)._run_interface(runtime)
    139         try:
    140             # Matlab can leave the terminal in a barbbled state


/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/nipype/interfaces/base.pyc in _run_interface(self, runtime, correct_return_codes)
   1378         setattr(runtime, 'dependencies', get_dependencies(executable_name,
   1379                                                           runtime.environ))
-> 1380         runtime = run_command(runtime, output=self.inputs.terminal_output)
   1381         if runtime.returncode is None or \
   1382                         runtime.returncode not in correct_return_codes:

/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/nipype/interfaces/base.pyc in run_command(runtime, output, timeout)
   1150         result['merged'] = [r[1] for r in temp]
   1151     if output == 'allatonce':
-> 1152         stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
   1153         result['stdout'] = stdout.split('\n')
   1154         result['stderr'] = stderr.split('\n')

/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.pyc in communicate(self, input)
    752             return (stdout, stderr)
    753
--> 754         return self._communicate(input)
    755
    756

/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.pyc in _communicate(self, input)
   1310
   1311             if _has_poll:
-> 1312                 stdout, stderr = self._communicate_with_poll(input)
   1313             else:
   1314                 stdout, stderr = self._communicate_with_select(input)

/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.pyc in _communicate_with_poll(self, input)
   1364             while fd2file:
   1365                 try:
-> 1366                     ready = poller.poll()
   1367                 except select.error, e:
   1368                     if e.args[0] == errno.EINTR:
```

I have read other `subprocess` problems in this site but they all are related with `Popen()`. In my case something wrong with `poller.poll()`. It does not process anymore when it reaches this line.

Comment: Could it have something to do with that matlab only is single thread you think?

Comment: I dont think the problem is related with matlab. Actually, the same code works on my mac. I think the problem is on computer that I use on a server. Somehow it can not complete `_communicate_with_poll`.

Answer (score 0):

I failed to replicate this behaviour (aka "works for me!"). Which version of nipype are you using?

Comment: '{'nibabel_version': '1.3.0', 'networkx_version': '1.6', 'numpy_version': '1.6.1', 'sys_platform': 'linux2', 'sys_version': '2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2013, 20:03:06) \n[GCC 4.6.3]', 'commit_source': 'archive substitution', 'commit_hash': '162f65d', 'pkg_path': '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/nipype', 'sys_executable': '/usr/bin/python', 'traits_version': '4.0.0', 'scipy_version': '0.9.0'}'

Comment: I just re-installed nipype now but again the same problem. Something wrong in `poller.poll()`. Even this one gets stuck : `python -c "import nipype; nipype.test()"`. Exactly at the same location.

Comment: nipype.__version__ ? can you run anything using Popen?

Comment: I'm away of sever for now but it must be the last version because I just re-installed it today by using NeuroDebian. I can use Popen without any problem and Gzip code([link](http://nipy.sourceforge.net/nipype/devel/cmd_interface_devel.html)) . But cannot call matlab, mipav or even simplest code on commandline. It gets stucks always. I even tried to run the code with admin account. It works on my mac but not on ubuntu. I think something wrong in base.py like parent function waiting for child and it gets stuck.

Comment: >>> nipype.__version__
'0.9.1'

Comment: MatlabCommand codes are running now after the server backup. So it was about server.